# Ajax get request succeds on localhost but fails online

Tags: json, ajax, wordpress, rest, api

I'm try to get data via an ajax get request in Wordpress and I wrote a script in javascript and another in php to handle it.

The code for javascript is the following:

```
window.loadServices = function loadServices(){
var data = {
          action: 'get_services',
          perpage: '6',
        };
$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: sendbooking.ajaxurl,
 data: data,
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function (response) {
   post = response.data;
   console.log(response);
   $.each(post, function(){
     elem = $(this)[0];
     media = elem._links['wp:featuredmedia']
     var media_href;
     $.each(media, function(){
       media_href = $(this)[0].href;
     })
     // console.log(elem);

     var image;

     $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: media_href,
       dataType: 'JSON',
       success: function(data){
         image = data.source_url;
       },
       async: false,
     })

     $('.services .elements .elements-container').append(
      $('<div />', {
        class: 'loader',
      }).append(
        $('<img />', {
          src: '/wp-content/themes/farmhouse/assets/images/loader.gif'
        })
      )
     )

     setTimeout(function(){
       $('.loader').fadeOut();
     }, 2000);
     $('.services .elements .elements-container').append(
       $('<div />', {
         class: 'element '+elem.type,
       }).append(
           $('<a />', {
             href: elem.link
           }).append(
             $('<div />', {
               class: 'element-image',
             }).append(
               $('<img />', {
                 src: image,
               })
             )
           )
        ).append(
          $('<h5 />', {
            class: 'element-title',
          }).append(
            $('<a />', {
              href: elem.link,
              text: elem.title.rendered
            })
          )
        )
     )
     setTimeout(function(){
       $('.loader').remove();
     }, 2000);
   })
  },
 });
}
```

This is instead the code for php:

```
if(!function_exists('get_services')):
    function get_services(){

        $data = $_GET;
        $json_feed = get_site_url() . '/wp-json/wp/v2/service?per_page='.$data['perpage'];
       $json = file_get_contents($json_feed);
       $json_decoded = json_decode($json);

        wp_send_json_success($json_decoded);

 }

 add_action('wp_ajax_get_services', 'get_services');
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_services', 'get_services');
endif;
```

The problem I'm having is that on localhost, this works fine, I get the content I need, without any problem. When I'm going to deploy the site on line, the ajax doesn't retrieve anything. Throwing console.logs, I noticed that the scripts fail when getting data from the api url (file_get_contents), but if you go there directly via browser's address bar, or through postman, data are served correctly. (You can test: http://www.dsoftwarelab.it/ilpiastrino/wp-json/wp/v2/service?per_page=6).

I really don't know how to solve it, since I've really tried everything.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1 : You don't have access rights on server.**

If you have root access, edit php.ini, usually located at /etc/php.ini.

If you dont have root access, try to add `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 'On');` or `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', '1');.`

If you can't see php.ini, try using phpinfo() in a PHP script to find the php.ini location.

**Case 2 : You have miss the SSL parameter in .**

```
$url= 'https://example.com';

$arrContextOptions=array(
      "ssl"=>array(
            "verify_peer"=>false,
            "verify_peer_name"=>false,
        ),
    );  

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
```

**Case 3 : 403 FORBIDDEN**

The server responds with an "403 FORBIDDEN" status code. So file_get_contents() works fine, but the server you are trying to access (or a proxy or something in between) dont allow it.

Comment: Tried to set those values, but it doesn't register anything (locally it does). 

There is no ssl enabled.

The server gives status 200 when performing that action.

Comment: @LuigiBriganti is it your file content reponse? dump data in file.

Comment: Archaeologists.

Comment: @Coder what do you mean?

Comment: @VasimShaikh the content response, in localhost is an array containing my data, but online the result is "false", like the server isn't able to read any data from the url provided. Is this I don't understand.

Comment: It seems that is a server problem. I gave up and made the call only in php. Thanks anyway for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Do not convert json to array. comment this line `$json_decoded = json_decode($json);`

```
if(!function_exists('get_services')):
    function get_services(){

        $data = $_GET;
        $json_feed = get_site_url() . '/wp-json/wp/v2/service?per_page='.$data['perpage'];
        $json = file_get_contents($json_feed);  

        //dont need this line
        //$json_decoded = json_decode($json);

        wp_send_json_success($json);

    }

 add_action('wp_ajax_get_services', 'get_services');
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_services', 'get_services');
endif;
```

Comment: if I don't decode json in php, then I have to do it in javascript with JSON.parse and the result is the same, because all I get from wp_send_json_success is a string that contain my json, useless with the js scritp I provided (have you checked it?).

Comment: you should use jsonparse